# concatenating a list of dataframes with zero values using rbind

Tags: r, rbind

I have a list of dataframes which I wanted to concatenate

```
 data List of 3  ###list of 3 dataframes

 AT1: 'data.frame': 1 obs of 2 varibles
 $neighbor: chr "ATa"
 $node: chr "AT1"

 AT2: 'data.frame': 0 obs of 2 varibles
 $neighbor: chr(0)
 $node: chr(0)

 AT3: 'data.frame': 4 obs of 2 varibles
 $neighbor: chr[1:4] "ATe" "ATf" "ATg" "ATh"
 $node: chr[1:4] "AT3" "AT3" "AT3" "AT3"
```

When I try to concatenate the dataframes using

```
  concatdata<-do.call("rbind",data)
```

I get the following

```
dataframe

node  neighbor

AT1       ATa
AT3       ATe
AT3       ATf
AT3       ATg
AT3       ATh
```

I would like that the zero valued dataframe is included as follows. This is for further computations. How do I do that?

node  neighbor

```
AT1       ATa
AT2       0 or as NA
AT3       ATe
AT3       ATf
AT3       ATg
AT3       ATh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create an `if/else` condition to create datasets that have 0 rows to NA

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(data, function(x) 
    if(nrow(x)==0) data.frame(neighbour = NA, node = "AT2") else x))[2:1]
```

---

Or another option is join

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(data)[data.frame(node = names(data)), on = "node"]
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(AT1 = structure(list(neighbour = "ATa", 
 node = "AT1"), .Names = c("neighbour", 
 "node"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), AT2 = structure(list(
neigbour = character(0), node = character(0)), .Names = c("neigbour", 
 "node"), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), AT3 = structure(list(
neighbour = c("ATe", "ATf", "ATg", "ATh"), node = c("AT3", 
"AT3", "AT3", "AT3")), .Names = c("neighbour", "node"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("AT1", "AT2", "AT3"))
```

Comment: I used the second option but that gives me an error saying I cannot merge columns which have zero or NAs. First option is not feasible because I have a large list, this is only a sample.

Comment: @Paul Both the options worked for me with the `data` in my post

Comment: Extremely sorry! I made a mistake, second one works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Paul No problem, I guess some structure difference might be there in original dataset